# How to handle a pointer to a pointer with Python and ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I'm trying to model a struct found in a library I'm wrapping, where the struct has a pointer-to-a-pointer like this:

```
typedef struct item_t {
  char* name;
}

typedef struct container_t {
  item_t **items;
}
```

How, when modeling with Python's `ctypes` module's `Structure` class, would I represent an array of pointers with a variable length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`POINTER`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.POINTER) and convert `item_t **` to `POINTER(POINTER(item_t))`:

```
from ctypes import *

class item_t(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('name', c_char_p),
    ]


class container_t(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('items', POINTER(POINTER(item_t))),
    ]
```